# Is there a way to write in a different language (Hebrew) in a spritefont?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

Whenever i try to type something in a different language (Hebrew), it gives me an error

"The character 'ש' (0x05e9) is not available in this SpriteFont."

Is there a way for this error to be solved?

Comment: Can you paste a bit of your code in?

Comment: See following webpage : https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteFont.  The standard sprite font is Ascii 7.  You need to use Extended Ascii as shown on webpage.

Comment: My initial guess would be that you need to create your own SpriteFont (that is, a bitmap image of sorts that contains every character you want), and then also a XML sheet that defines each ascii code and what character on the bitmap belongs to which code. At least I think that's how the process of creating custom SpriteFonts goes...